# how to access to ScrollControll of a class from another class in flutter?

Tags: flutter, listview, scrollcontroller

Hello i`m new in flutter.
I made a special listView for myself and made a controller for it.
In the main page, I have called my own list view and I have a button that I want to execute the following method by pressing it from the Main class and my list view scrolls inside another class.
scroll method:

```
void _animateToIndex(int index) {
_controller.animateTo(
index * 50,
duration: Duration(seconds: 1),
curve: Curves.fastOutSlowIn,
  );
}
```

In fact, I want to execute the method of another class that contains my scrollview from the Main class.

my listView class:

```
class CustomNumberScroller extends StatefulWidget {

const CustomNumberScroller(
  {Key? key, required this.curStep, required this.pageNumberOfMainDart})
  : super(key: key);

@override
State<CustomNumberScroller> createState() => _CustomNumberScrollerState();
}

final dataKey = new GlobalKey();

final ScrollController _controller = ScrollController();

void _animateToIndex(int index) {
_controller.animateTo(
index * 50,
duration: Duration(seconds: 1),
curve: Curves.fastOutSlowIn,
 );
}

class _CustomNumberScrollerState extends State<CustomNumberScroller> {
 @override
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
 Size media = MediaQuery.of(context).size;

 return ...

   }
}
```

Comment: Use provider and consumers

Answer (score 0):

you can use state management as provide and put scroll controller in class and access to controller in any place in widget tree

hope that helps you

[get started with provider](https://pub.dev/packages/provider)